# Ignore dynamic named folders

Tags: git, gitignore

My test tool stores snapshots of all screens it encounters in a `snapshots` folder and I don't want to version control them. The `action` folder however is dynamic and it creates a new folder every time the test is executed, like `action1`, `action2`, `action3`, etc.
So I have this now, but it doesn't work:

```
Test/Action*/Snapshots/
```

How can I set `gitignore` that it wil ignore this?

Comment: Do you want to ignore everything under `Action*`? If so `Test/Action*` (make sure the case matches, i.e. `Action` vs. `action`)

Comment: Please check once more, taking account of case. For me it works.

Comment: No, everything within the ``snapshots`` folder, because there can als be other folders, like ``Test/Action*/Files/`` which should not be ignored

Comment: I see I forgot to match the case, stupid me!

Comment: voting to close as typo, as that seems to be the issue